# Rank change based on the original rank?

Tags: ranking, weights, controlling-for-a-variable

My question is on how to "properly" weigh rank changes. For example, in the scenario of faculty placement, it is harder to go to a better university when you are already in a good university. In this case, the absolute value of rank change is not as informative.

For example, a doctorate graduate `A` in an institution ranked as the number 5 is hired by the top 1 institution. Then the rank change of `A` is $r_{diff}^{A} = r_{phd}^A-r_{hire}^A=5-1=4$. In the meantime, `B` graduated from No. 25 is hired by No. 21. Then $r_{diff}^{B} = r_{phd}^B-r_{hire}^B=25-21=4=r_{diff}^{A}$. Although they both go up 4 ranks, the difficulty is different. It would be similar in the case of downward hiring or institution inbreeding.

Is there a standard way for such situation that can control for the original rank?

Comment: Ideally just use the original data instead. If they've disappeared, use any distribution you like as reference distribution to derive quantitative scores, e.g. rankits https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankit

Comment: @NickCox Thanks for the reply but I am confused by "If they've disappeared".

Comment: Do you have the original data behind the ranks? If not, they have disappeared.